# Some subtle point about $\bar{\partial}-$Poincare lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

The lemma is stated as follows:

$\bar{\partial}$-Poincaré lemma in one variable Consider an open neighbourhood of the closure of a bounded one-dimensional disc $B_{\varepsilon} \subset$ $\bar{B}_{\varepsilon} \subset U \subset \mathbb{C}$. For $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(U)$ the function
$$
g(z):=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{B_{\varepsilon}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} d w \wedge d \bar{w}
$$
on $B_{\varepsilon}$ satisfies $\alpha=\bar{\partial} g$

---

The question is why the arguement does not applicable to the case $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(B_{\epsilon})$ directly?

---

The proof goes like this:

Note first, that for $w=x+i y$ one has $d w \wedge d \bar{w}=(d x+i d y) \wedge(d x-i d y)=$ $-2 i d x \wedge d y$. The existence of $g$ as well as the assertion $\alpha=\bar{\partial} g$ will be shown by splitting $g$ into two parts. This splitting will depend on a chosen point $z_{0} \in B_{\varepsilon}$ or rather on a neighborhood of such a point.

Let $z_{0} \in B:=B_{\varepsilon}$ and let $\psi: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with compact $\operatorname{supp}(\psi) \subset B$ and such that $\left.\psi\right|_{V} \equiv 1$ for some open neighbourhood of $z_{0} \in V \subset B$. If $f_{1}:=\psi \cdot f$ and $f_{2}:=(1-\psi) \cdot f$, then $f=f_{1}+f_{2}$. In order to see that the above integral is well-defined, we consider first the following integrals
$$
g_{i}(z):=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{B} \frac{f_{i}(w)}{w-z} d w \wedge d \bar{w}, i=1,2 .
$$
Since $\left.f_{2}\right|_{V} \equiv 0$, the second one is obviously well defined for $z \in V$. The first integral can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
g_{1}(z) &=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{B} \frac{f_{1}(w)}{w-z} d w \wedge d \bar{w} \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{f_{1}(w)}{w-z} d w \wedge d \bar{w}, \text { since } \operatorname{supp}\left(f_{1}\right) \subset B \text { is compact } \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{f_{1}(u+z)}{u} d u \wedge d \bar{u}, \text { for } u:=w-z \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} f_{1}\left(z+r e^{i \varphi}\right) e^{-i \varphi} d \varphi \wedge d r, \text { for } u=r e^{i \varphi}
\end{aligned}
$$

The last integral is clearly well-defined. Since the integral defining $g$ splits into the two integrals just considered, we see that the function $g$ in the assertion is well-defined on $V$ and thus everywhere on $B$
....

Comment: You are wanting to integrate around a disk, so it's nice to know your function is analytic on the whole of the disk, meaning it's analytic in a neighborhood of each point of the boundary of the disk. Glue these neighborhoods (along with the disk itself) to get $U$.

Comment: To clarify, the question is not about correctness of the lemma, but about vanishing Dolbeault cohomology of a disk, right? And the prospective problem is, if $\alpha$ is defined in $B_{\epsilon}$ we have no guarantee that $\alpha$ extends to a larger disk, so "we can't apply the lemma"? <> If that's right, it appears we can use the lemma with $U = B_{\epsilon}$ equal to our original disk, and apply the lemma to an arbitrary disk compactly contained in $U = B_{\epsilon}$. That is, the $B_{\epsilon}$ we start with is not the $B_{\epsilon}$ in the lemma.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang  , thank you for your clarify, maybe my question can be stated as follows: I have checked very carefully  I found the argument can be directly apply to the $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(B_{\epsilon})
$ instead of taking $U$. If you are familiar with the argument for the lemma above, can you help me find which step does not apply to $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(B_{\epsilon})$?

Comment: You know if the argument in the lemma above apply directly to $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(B_{\epsilon})
$, there is not need of the exhaustion argument. However I can't find why it does not apply directly to $\alpha=f d \bar{z} \in \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(B_{\epsilon})
$?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang , does my question make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the gist is the following. The proof I am familiar with proceeds by using a bump function $\rho$ with  $\rho = 1$ on $|w|\le \epsilon$ and $\rho = 0$ outside $|w|=\epsilon'>\epsilon$. The proof then applies the generalized Cauchy integral formula to compute $\bar\partial g$ on $B_\epsilon$, where $g$ is defined by integrating with $\rho f$ (not $f$) on $B_{\epsilon'}$. So your question seems to be misstated (the integral is over a larger disk) and also ignores the proof.

Second, suppose you took $f$ to be smooth on $B_\epsilon$ with a bad enough singularity as $|w|\to\epsilon^-$ so that the integral defining $g$ does not even converge. (Consider, for example, $f(w)=(\epsilon-|w|)^{-1}$ or worse.)

Comment: Hi Ted -- I think the OP's formula works fine as long as $f$ is smooth on $\overline B_\epsilon$. This version is proved in Griffiths & Harris (p. 5). If $f$ is only defined on $B_\epsilon$, it's still true that there's a $g$ such that $\overline\partial g=f\,d\overline z$, but it requires a more delicate argument involving a sequence of bump functions of the type you mentioned.

Comment: Well, being smooth on $\overline B_\epsilon$ gives us a slightly larger $\epsilon'>\epsilon$ as I suggested, right? :) [I grant that I am rusty and haven't taught this in a number of years.]

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were saying the integral has to computed over a larger disk. All I'm saying is that you can solve the problem on $B_\epsilon$ by integrating over $\overline B_\epsilon$

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  , I have updated the question , the version of the proof above take bump function inside $B_\epsilon$?(You can found the proof on Huybrechts complex geometry  page 44
) I know this statement looks like this roots in the generalized Cauchy formula. However as we see if we take $\psi f$ localized inside $B_{\epsilon}$, there is no issue about boundary ?

Comment: @yili You agree that I gave you an easy counterexample if you do not require continuity up to the boundary? Then the integral may not even converge.

Comment: Thank you @Ted Shifrin  ,After a long thought, I finally make it clear, I realized this statement does not involve any geometry.What the statement did is show that $f(w)/(w-z)dw \wedge d\bar{w}$ does not really have a singularity at $z$ as long as $f$ is very nice for example continuous up to boundary ,this is standard technique in analysis for example proving something involve convolution with the good kernel.